# Why am I getting an error regarding Bolts framework and FacebookSDK when I'm not even using Bolts?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Getting this error

```
framework not found Bolts for architecture x86_64
```

Followed Facebook's guide word for word, but the only place I can think of an error with linking happening is in the Build Settings for Framework Search Paths. All I currently am attempting in the app is to add a Facebook Login in button, simply visually to make sure it's loading visually. No method functionality is added, but I can't even build the project in this current state.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

1. Open the project in Xcode.
2. Go to where you extracted the FacebookSDK. If you're using Mac OSX,
   it should be available in `Documents/FacebookSDK`.
3. Grab the
   `Bolts.framework` file and drop into your Frameworks folder in
   Xcode for your project.

It should build now.

Comment: Not working for me. I'm using Pods and still getting the error.

Answer (score 7):

you need to add Bolts.framework to your project

Answer (score 6):

As of 24th of April 2019, the [Facebook SDK in Swift](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk) repo inside this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/commit/ef89eb8d48908d80dd111d05dc6317bb8d923d29):

> Removed Bolts from Swift SDK

So you will have to add Bolts to your pod file. 
FYI if you're using **Swift 5** you will need to use the [Bolts in Objc](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC) because currently [Bolts for Swift](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift) only support Swift 4.1.

For Swift 5 in your pod file:

```
pod 'Bolts'
```

To answer your question, from Bolts GitHub:

> Bolts is a collection of low-level libraries designed to make
>   developing mobile apps easier. Bolts was designed by Parse and
>   Facebook for our own internal use

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

It looks like [Bolts for Swift](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift) now support Swift 5.

Comment: easiest option so far

Comment: perfect solution if you are upgrading facebook sdk from 4.x.x to 5.x.x because Bolts library exclusion

Answer (score 2):

In my case I opened the project instead of the workspace (using pods)

Comment: Opening the `.xcworkspace` instead of the project was the answer to me. I'm working on a project created with React Native.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build Settings of your project.
Search for Framework Search Paths.
Add to debug: "$(inherited)".
Do the same for release.
Re-build the project.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do pod update and then open your xcworkspace. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Late but might help
- add Bolts.Framework
- also remember to do as warnings shown during installation[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Run "pod update" in terminal (if you not updated)
> 2. Remove "Bolts" framework from "Other Linker Flags" (Click on target->Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags)