# Why it shows "ld: framework not found Bolts"

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods, bolts-framework

After I install facebook sdk, when I build my project, it shows:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/liyuanliu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/c5-dsovqtraubbdgxbqrmiexjmlysxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/liyuanliu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/c5-dsovqtraubbdgxbqrmiexjmlysxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/liyuanliu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/c5-dsovqtraubbdgxbqrmiexjmlysxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/liyuanliu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/c5-dsovqtraubbdgxbqrmiexjmlysxq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit'
ld: framework not found Bolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But when I install facebook and bolts, it shows I install them successfully:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.14.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.14.0)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.14.0)
Using Firebase (3.4.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.3.0)
Using FirebaseAppIndexing (1.0.4)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.0.4)
```

Below is my build phases image :

[image]

And below cannot find bolts framework image

[image]

I cannot find the `FBXXXX.framework`
[image]

After I add frameworks, it still exits:
[image]

Comment: you should answer your question instead of editing it. Also please change the title to something along the lines : Bolts framework not found [Xcode 7] or stuff to make it more helpful to future readers

Comment: If someone is using Swift 5 and latest FB SDK (FB SDK in Swift version 5.x.x) please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56722855/4260691

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by deleting the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx while xcode was closed and then reopened xcode and did a clean + build. All was fixed up when xcode rebuilt the derived data for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps

1. From Podfile directory run below commands in terminal

   `pod deintegrate`

   `pod install`
2. Clean Derived Data folder from Xcode
3. Perform fresh clean build

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project->TARGETS-Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries` Attach your `Bolts` library here.

[image]

Now click on + button ->[image]

Now Click on Add Other.. Button->Find the FBSDK framework on your computer & attach it. Compile & run your application .

Comment: Press Command & Space button , it Open Search Bar on mac , Type FBSDK etc. you will get the location of FB framework. Else you can download FB SDK for iOS here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

Comment: I just found another way to solve it, see my updates. But still thanks for your  suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,  I found a solution to solve this problem. In project->targets->build settings->framework search path, there are many paths already existed. I download 4 frameworks(bolts.framework and 3 other FBXXXX.framework) and copy all of them inside one of these existing paths.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the suggestion at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started of not `Deselect Copy items into destination group's folder.` is not appropriate on Xcode 8.0, the most popular atm. Dragging the frameworks would **move** them to the new `Frameworks` folder.

So follow the tutorial but **keep the tic**k on `Copy items into destination group's folder`

Answer (score 0):

> **Finally got solution for them if they are using pod**

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.43.0'


pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.43.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answer on the behalf of the author of the post*:

Finally, I found a solution to solve this problem. In `project->targets->build settings->framework` search path, there are many paths that already existed. I download 4 frameworks (`bolts.framework` and 3 other `FBXXXX.framework`) and copy all of them inside one of these existing paths.